# Snowflake REGEX to identify if column contains any digit

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I currently have `select REGEXP_LIKE(col, '[0-9]+')` which seems to return `True` only if all the characters in the string are numeric.

For example, it returns `True` for `12345` but `False` for something like `100 Apple St`.

What is the necessary regex pattern to return True in both examples above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a column contains any digit, you can modify your current pattern to use the `.*` character to match any number of characters before or after the digit(s):

```
SELECT REGEXP_LIKE(col, '.*[0-9].*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking a column that might not only contain numbers using `REGEXP_COUNT`.

### COPY-PASTA-EXAMPLE

```sql
-- RETURN ROWS "CONTAINING ONLY 1 OR MORE DIGITS"
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES 
      ('1','ONE'), 
      ('12345 ','ONE-TWO-THREE-FOUR-FIVE'), 
      ('100 Apple St.','ONE-HUNDRED APPLE STREET'), 
      ('3 FIFTY','THREE FIFTY'), 
      ('NINETY-FIVE','NINETY-SEVEN'), 
      (NULL, NULL)
     ) AS FAKE_ROWS (A_NUMERIC_FIELD, A_TEXT_VARCHAR_FIELD) 
WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(A_NUMERIC_FIELD, '.*[0-9].*') <> 0;  
-- THE FOLLOWING ALSO WORK EXACTLY THE SAME.
-- WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(A_NUMERIC_FIELD, '.*[[:digit:]].*') <> 0;  
-- WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(A_NUMERIC_FIELD, '^.*\\d+.*$') > 0;
```

RETURNS:

| A_NUMERIC_FIELD | A_TEXT_VARCHAR_FIELD |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ONE |
| 12345 | ONE-TWO-THREE-FOUR-FIVE |
| 100 Apple St. | ONE-HUNDRED APPLE STREET |
| 3 FITFTY | THREE FIFTY |

Excluded were: `NINETY-FIVE` and `NULL VALUES`

DOCS:

- [General Usage Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp#label-regexp-general-usage-notes)
- [POSIX basic and extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended)